# When to use "love to do something" and "love doing something"?

Tags: infinitives, gerunds, gerund-vs-infinitive

OK, I searched similar questions on https://english.stackexchange.com/ and it seems that people say that

> *to love to do something=prefer to do something*
>
> *to love doing something=enjoy doing something*

OK, see conversation 1:

> **Tom**: *I'm going to wear my casual t-shirt to the party*
>
> **Jack**: *On the contrary, I love to dress up*

Now conversation 2:

> **Tom**: *I like my casual t-shirt very much*
>
> **Jack**: *On the contrary, I love dressing up*

So, *am I understanding it correctly?*

If not, when do you use “**to love to do something**” and “**to love doing something*”?**

Comment: The link shows nothing. I thought it was going to lead me to this type of page: http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22love+to%22+infinitive+gerund

Answer (score 0):

The sentences **I love to play basketball** and **I love playing basketball** are totally identical in meaning.

But if you're saying that you would really like to do something (perhaps as a response to an offer), you'd say **I'd love to**.  If you turn that into a complete sentence, you'd choose the infinitive only:

**--How would you like to shoot some hoops with me some day?**

**--I'd love to./I'd love to shoot some hoops with you.**

Using the -ing form here is far less common, and sounds a little off.